# Neo4J - Create nodes from JSON file

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following JSON file **example.json** which I can parse using this query.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("example.json") YIELD value
UNWIND value.items as items
RETURN items
```

This gives me the following result:

```
{
  "@type": "A",
  "id": "foo",
  "title": "bar"
},
{
  "@type": "B",
  "id": "foo",
  "title": "bar"
},
{
  "@type": "C",
  "id": "foo",
  "title": "bar"
}
```

Next, I would like to create nodes (A, B, C) from these properties with the value of **@type** as their label name. How can I do this using cypher queries?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it!

```
CALL apoc.load.json("example.json") YIELD value
UNWIND value.items as items
CREATE (n:items {name: items.`@type`})
```